# How to compare similar data in Mono, Flux

Tags: spring

I'm new to reacitve webclient andi have two request going on simultaneously, but i need to compare both repsonse data. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by two requests?

Comment: I am mkaing two seprate get request to get similar data put in want to compare them. one request: Mono<Apex> targetApex = .......
          second request Mono<Apex> sourceApex = .... . I know i can get data if i block, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I would assume that you want to use some kind of `zip` operator on the `Mono`s. Reactor has `zipWith` which can be used in the following way:

```
targetApex.zipWith(sourceApex).subscribe(apex-> {
    // apex is type of Tuple2 which has getT1 and getT2 methods
    int result = apex.getT1().compare(apex.getT2());
    // do something with the result
});
```